# Subtract 3 Columns in Google Sheet at Once

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help me? I'm using array formula for all. And basically I need to subract 3 columns, is there a way to do that? Im managing inventory.
[image: In the picture shown, Column C - Column D equals Column F, and what I need is I want to add the column E to the subtraction]

In the picture shown, Column C - Column D equals Column F, and what I need is I want to add the column E to the subtraction

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={"Total Inventory"; INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,E2:E+C2:C-D2:D))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your present function

```
if(A1:A="",,E1:E+C1:C-D1:D)
```